# How to code automatic uncompression of files in sh?

Tags: shell-script, shell, cat

I'm coding a shell script, that processes log-files. *Sometimes* the files may be compressed -- and have the appropriate suffix in the file name.

I'd like to add the decompression to the file-processing pipeline in such cases:

```
case "$file" in:
*.gz)  READER="gzip -cd" ;;
*.bz2) READER="bzip2 -cd" ;;
...
*)     READER="cat" ;;
esac
$READER < $file | processing
```

This works, but I do not like it, because, when the file is uncompressed, `cat` is invoked uselessly. I'd like processing to open the file directly in this case:

```
< $file processing
```

I tried using `eval` and making the `|` part of the `$READER`, but that messes up the *processing* pipeline as eval is applied to that as well...

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should double quote your variables.  and define READER to be an array rather than a single string.  e.g. `*.gz) READER=(gzip -cd) ;;` ..... `"${READER[@]}" < "$file" | processing`

Comment: Thank you, but this looks like a bashism -- my script can not rely on `bash` being available.

Comment: something I've used several times in the past is to rely on the fact that `lesspipe` already implements all of this (and more).  So if you have GNU `less` installed, and don't want to/can't install `ucat`, you could replace all of the code in your example with `eval $(lesspipe)` and `less "$file" | processing`

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Can't rely on any of the "non-standard" tools being present -- the script has to work with stock `sh` and not only on BSD and Linux, but on dinasaurs like HP-UX as well.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is that there is not even the slightest reason to care about a Useless Use Of Cat ("UUOC").

In this case, it's not even a "useless" use - `cat` is serving the very useful purpose of being the default filter so that you don't have to write extra lines of code to handle a special case.

Unnecessary complexity is a far worse programming "crime" than a UUOC.

BTW, if the `cat` really bothers you, you can use `ucat` from the `unp` tool set and avoid re-inventing the wheel.  `unp` doesn't seem to have a home page, but it's packaged for debian and ubuntu at least (currently maintained by debian developer Eduard Block).

```
Package: unp
Version: 2.0~pre7+nmu1
Installed-Size: 133
Maintainer: Eduard Bloch <blade@debian.org>
Architecture: all
Suggests: bzip2, unrar | unrar-free, xdms, p7zip | p7zip-full, unzip, cabextract,
orange
Description-en: unpack (almost) everything with one command
 unp is a small perl script which makes extraction of any archive files
 a bit easier. It support several compressors and archiver programs,
 chooses the right one(s) automatically and extracts one or more files
 in one go.
 .
 You may also want to install some non-free packages like "unace-nonfree",
 "unrar-nonfree" and "lha" to extract archives of these types.
```

Comment: By Moore's law over the last 15 years, for example, computers have become 1024 times more powerful -- faster cores, more of them, bigger caches, wider pipes. The computing experience -- not so much. Because programmers "ate" a vast share of the improvements for their own convenience and to avoid "unnecessary" complexity...

Comment: if you're writing extra code just to avoid something trivial like a UUOC then that's unnecessary complexity.  You've add complexity (and the potential for more bugs) just to avoid something that isn't a problem and doesn't consume noticeable resources (certainly less than the extra code needed to avoid running `cat`).   Forking `cat` thousands of times in a loop would be bad.  Forking it one extra time is completely trivial and irrelevant.

Comment: btw, my computer is many times faster than it was 15 years ago - even after all the greedy time-wasting programmer convenience code-crimes.  Also BTW, I/O speeds (even PCI-e x4 SSDs and 10+gigait NICs) haven't kept up with CPU/RAM/Cache/etc improvements - they're they bottleneck.  They'll probably **always** be the bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, your computer is much faster. Maybe, even a 100 times. But nowhere near the 1024 times... But, whatever. As is obvious, I _already know_, how to implement it using `cat`. My entire question is how to avoid the extra memory-copying involved in this method. Telling me, I should not try to avoid it, is _not_ an answer.

Comment: You asked for suggestions, I gave you a suggestion (in fact, I've given multiple suggestions - you don't like any of them).  "There's no need to care about UUOC" *IS* an answer - and probably the best you'll get - even if you don't like it.

Comment: What is this mythical 'orange' tool btw?

Comment: 'orange' is here, but it needs some patching to compile with modern auto{make, ..}: https://sourceforge.net/p/synce/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/orange/